After upgrading Apache Kafka from 2.7 to 3.7 performance test results degrade so much
After upgrading Kafka from 2.7 to 3.7, we benchmark a topic with Kafka's kafka-producer-perf-test.sh. the scale of perf test results change. for example, the latency moves from 5ms to 60ms.
bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server X:9092  --create --topic perf-test compression.type=snappy --config min.insync.replicas=2 --config retention.ms=84000000 --partitions 9 --replication-factor 3  --command-config /Y


After investigating we found the result is not because of the change in the Kafka version itself but it's because of updating the client that runs the test,kafka-producer-perf-test.sh
So remember that in upgrading this bash file from version 2.8 to 3.0, there are some changes that don't let you compare test results. These changes are listed below.

changed default values of ack=all, enable.idempotence=false
the benchmark payload changed as described here. KAFKA-12611

